# Trying to read the text of an FTP website into a string in pythong

Tags: python, string, ftp

This is the site I can open in Chrome and see text:

ftp://ftp.cmegroup.com/pub/settle/stlags

Any idea how to read this into a string in python?

Comment: You're gonna need a library that does a request to `ftp` servers, and get the text out of the request response.

Comment: looks also like it is a CSV type file, correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Don`t know if this helps but this will get you the html of a website:

```
import urllib.request
url = "ftp://ftp.cmegroup.com/pub/settle/stlags"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
htmlB=html.read()
htmlS = htmlB.decode()

print(htmlS)
```

Comment: Actually, `htmlB.decode()` returns a string, so `htmlS` is exactly what OP wanted.

Comment: Yeah but it looks like a table, i don`t know if he wanted to get that table as an array of strings.. I hope its what he was looking for though.

Comment: This is perfect! I just wanted to pull all the text into one string. I swear I tried this exact thing, but I guess I F'd it up somehow before. Thanks for the help!